# Border Bootstrap 4 se la sale de su container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Muy buenas, es un detalle pero es algo que quiero poner, hay un borde que separa los comentarios de las respuestas y se sale de todos los contenedores padre

Aquí les dejo el fragmento de código

```
<!-- COMMENTS -->
<div class="container mt-2 p-2" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8); border-radius: 5px">
<div>
  <form action="#" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control col-10">
    <div class="col-2 d-flex">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success col-11 m-auto" value="Enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div style= "background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);min-height:5em; border-radius:10px" class="border- 
top border-bottom mt-2">

<div id="comment" class="row p-1 border-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-2 d-flex">
    <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" class="m-auto" style="width:5em;border-radius:50%;background: 
 gray">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-11 col-10">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor facilis doloremque assumenda 
    quae error corporis quo! Reiciendis, 
      eum excepturi a, possimus non facere porro dolorum aliquam nam repellat aspernatur 
    necessitatibus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row p-1">
  <div id="reply" class="d-inline my-1 col-10 ml-auto">

    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, dolores a. Laborum 
      neque officiis nemo voluptates, 
      debitis est, laboriosam magni odit veritatis quidem vel reprehenderit praesentium laudantium 
     exercitationem quis ullam!.
      By:<a class="ml-auto" href="#">User</a></p>
    
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Responder" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Solo para aclarar los css en style son provisionales, posteriormente los pasare a una hoja de estilos )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en vez de poner `p-1` en los elementos con la clase `row`añade `m-1`, poner margen en vez de relleno, te dejo un ejemplo.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-primary">
 <!-- COMMENTS -->
 <div class="container mt-2 p-2" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8); border-radius: 5px">
  <div>
   <form action="#" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control col-10">
    <div class="col-2 d-flex">
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-success col-11 m-auto" value="Enviar">
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

  <div style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);min-height:5em; border-radius:10px" class="border-top border-bottom mt-2">

   <div id="comment" class="row m-1 border-bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-2 d-flex">
     <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" class="m-auto" style="width:5em;border-radius:50%;background: gray">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-10">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor facilis doloremque assumenda
      quae error corporis quo! Reiciendis,
      eum excepturi a, possimus non facere porro dolorum aliquam nam repellat aspernatur
      necessitatibus.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row m-1">
    <div id="reply" class="d-inline my-1 col-10 ml-auto">

     <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, dolores a. Laborum
      neque officiis nemo voluptates,
      debitis est, laboriosam magni odit veritatis quidem vel reprehenderit praesentium laudantium
      exercitationem quis ullam!.
      By:<a class="ml-auto" href="#">User</a></p>

     <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-10 col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control w-100">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-2 col-sm-3">
       <input type="submit" value="Responder" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```